# My question was answered in comments

Tags: discussion

I've asked a few questions where the answer is simple and someone answers it in the comments.  For example: [What are the differences between Configuration and Developer Sandboxes?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4355/what-are-the-differences-between-configuration-and-developer-sandboxes)

What should we do about "answering" these questions?  Ask commenter to repost as an answer so it can be accepted?  Or are questions like this not a good fit for SFSE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the comment really does completely answer the question, then sure, ask the commenter to repost as an answer. Sometimes another user will come along and edit additional content into the answer (maybe a code snippet) and it becomes even more useful.

Oftentimes, though, you'll ask the commenter to expand their comment into an answer. This is probably the most common case, I think.

Comment: +1 — I ask for them to rewrite the comment as an answer so that it can be accepted and obvious to others who have the same question.